# double functions, fstreams, and more fun

Tags: c++

The big picture is to take information from one file to another file. I've done that and it works well. The next thing I need to do is find the highest value from the new file. The basic format is like this: I have a bunch of "workers", I have the days they have worked, the hours & minutes they've worked. In the new file I have it formatted to show the pay rate (I enter the value as a cin) and then I have the total amount of money they made (everyone makes the same amount.. that which is in the cin). For some reason, I cannot make a function (that works) that will extract the persons name that makes the most money, and how much money that is. I got a little frustrated and was trying whatever I could so the new function is sloppy and ridiculous, but I was hoping you could help. To keep this a general question and not a specific question, I was wondering if you guys could just explain how to do something like this (finding the highest value & outputting it WITH the name of the person.. so essentially a double for the money and a string with the persons name) using parts of my code as an example:

```
  #include <iostream>

  #include <fstream>

  #include <iomanip>

  #include <string>

  #include <cstdlib>

  using namespace std;

  void getandprintaddress (ifstream&, ofstream&); // this function will be used to get the data from one file and input it into the next with the total amount of money made from each person as well as the next function
  double highestpaid(double& highesttotal, double& totalpay, string highestpaidemp, string name); // this function is what will be used to find the highest amount of money and the person who has it
  void name(); // This is to input my name in the file.

  struct employees // This is the structure with all of the information that will be used to calculate everything. 
  {
     string name; // person's name
     string highestpaidemp; // highest paid employee
     string address; // the address of the employee
     string address2;
     int days; // days worked
     int hours; //hours worked
     double minutes; // minutes worked
      int total_hours; // total hours worked
     double totalpay; // total pay
     double payrate; // pay rate
     double total_minutes; // minutes worked
     double total_time; // total hours and minutes worked
     double highesttotal; // the highest total amount of money made between all employees.

};

int main(){
    ifstream inputFile; 
    ofstream outputFile;
    getandprintaddress(inputFile, outputFile);



return 0;
}

void getandprintaddress(ifstream& inputFile, ofstream& outputFile) // the main function that will be used to get and output all the information.
    {
        struct employees();
        ifstream getdata;
        ofstream outdata;
        int employees_t;

        employees employeeinfo;

        string inputfile;
        string outputfile;

cout << "What is the name of your input file? "<<endl; // this will be the file you open
            cin>>inputfile; 


    getdata.open(inputfile.c_str());


    if(getdata.fail()){ // this is meant to be used if someone enters a file that isn't there
            cout << "The input file has failed to open. \n";
            exit(1);
    }


    cout << "What is the name of your output file? \n"; // what you want the title of the new file to be.
                cin>>outputfile;
                outdata.open(outputfile.c_str());


if(outdata.fail())
{
   //This is if the new file is invalid

    cout << "The outputfile failed to open. \n";
    exit(1);


}


    cout << "How many employees are there? \n" ;
                    cin >> employees_t; // Enter how many employees there are

    cout << "What is the employees hourly payrate? \n";
                    cin >> employeeinfo.payrate; // how much each employee makes.

    for ( int info = 0; info < employees_t; info++)
         {
            employeeinfo.highesttotal = 0.0; // this will be needed for calculating the highest paid employee

            employeeinfo.total_minutes = 0.0; // This is needed to calculate total minutes

            employeeinfo.total_hours = 0; // Same as the total_minutes, but for hours instead.

            employeeinfo.total_time = 0.0; // Needed to calculate total time 

            string line1;

            getline(getdata, employeeinfo.name);

            outdata << "Name: " << employeeinfo.name <<endl; // employees name

            getline(getdata, employeeinfo.address);

            outdata << "Address: \n"; // Employees address

            outdata<< employeeinfo.address <<endl;

            getline(getdata, employeeinfo.address2);

            outdata <<employeeinfo.address2 <<endl;

            getdata >> employeeinfo.days;

            outdata << "Days worked: " <<employeeinfo.days << endl; // Days worked

            for (int totalworked=0; totalworked<employeeinfo.days; totalworked++)
                { 
                    // Because the employees work different amount of days, this loop is needed to post the individual information from each employee

                    getdata >> employeeinfo.hours >> employeeinfo.minutes;

                    employeeinfo.minutes = employeeinfo.minutes / 60;

                    employeeinfo.total_hours = employeeinfo.total_hours + employeeinfo.hours;

                    employeeinfo.total_minutes = employeeinfo.total_minutes + employeeinfo.minutes;

                    employeeinfo.total_time = employeeinfo.total_minutes + employeeinfo.total_hours;

                    employeeinfo.totalpay = employeeinfo.total_time * employeeinfo.payrate;

                    outdata << employeeinfo.hours <<" hours "<< employeeinfo.minutes*60 << " minutes"<< endl;

                }
            outdata << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1); // Setting the total hours worked to 1 decimal so that to include the minutes

            outdata << "Total hours worked: "<<employeeinfo.total_time<<endl; // Total hours worked

            outdata << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2); // Setting the decimal to two places

            outdata << "Hourly pay: $"<<employeeinfo.payrate << endl; //Hourly pay

            outdata << "Gross pay: $" <<employeeinfo.totalpay <<endl; // Gross pay

            getline(getdata,line1);

            getline(getdata,line1);

            outdata << "\n";

            double highestpaid(employeeinfo.highesttotal, employeeinfo.totalpay);
        }

    };
double highestpaid(double& highesttotal, double&totalpay, string highestpaidemp, string name)
    {

        if (highesttotal < totalpay)
        {
            highesttotal = totalpay;
            highestpaidemp = name;


        }

return highestpaid(double& highesttotal, double&totalpay, string highestpaidemp, string name);
    };
```

Comment: how is the file formatted? can you please indent your code and add comments? it's quite hard to read.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that! I needed to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to answer your general question rather than spend too long searching through your code, but hopefully should work for both.

You have your struct employee

Stick them all in a vector of employees (which i'll call workers)

```
vector<struct employee> workers
```

using a vector means you can just keep on adding more to the end, but an array would work too if you had a fixed number of workers

now each worker can be identified by an integer index, 0 to n-1, where n is number of workers. Now can just iterate through (quicker methods if very large number of workers but probably fine here) to find highest salary

```
double highestPay = 0; 
int highestPaidIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i++; i < n)
{
    if(workers[i].totalpay > highestPay)
    {
        highestPay = workers[i].totalpay;
        highestPaidIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Now highestPaidIndex is the index of the highest paid employee, who has name workers[highestPaidIndex].name and total earnings workers[highestPaidIndex].totalpay

Hope that solves both your general and specific question

Comment: I haven't worked with vectors before, but it seems like a really great idea. When I make the vector, what do I have to do to get all of the names & information in it?

Comment: so the vector i'm suggesting is made up of structs. you just define the values of any element of the struct in the vector. So if worker 2 has worked 10 hours just do workers[2].hoursWorked = 10 (or whatever your appropriate varible name is).    Of course you'd want to loop through all the workers, adding information to each from your file, initializing one big vector, contatining structs which themselves would contain all the information about each particular worker